# Simplified 'Getting Started' for a small Prism application

Tags: .net, wpf, prism

I would like to test the waters a little bit by converting a very simple WPF application to a Prism based application.  Can anyone give me a basic +- 5 step getting started process - what conceptual steps do I need, and I will do the required reading for details.  It just seems the developers guide offers too much detail to choose from.  After hours I can go and do some serious reading, but right now I would just like a very basic 'getting started' guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.

Have you downloaded Prism Library? If not, download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=3453ab2b-2067-41e4-b087-312d8385cf1b&displaylang=en) first.

Once you've Prism on your harddisk, you can start reading **Composite Application Guidance for WPF and Silverlight.chm** which you would find in your prism folder.

I would recommend you to read first this section "Quick Starts" which explains in brief everything you would need to know as a beginner. This section actually explains various techniques used to develop Composite Application. To explain each technique, it demonstrates the concept using two sample projects (one in WPF, other in  Silverlight). Once you finish reading this section and understand the sample projects (even incompletely), you can start reading other section, such as "Technical Concepts" which explains the same techniques which you've read in "Quick Starts" **but in great details.**

After reading these two sections, I think, you would know prism fairly well. And don't forget to do some experimemt with the examples given in the "Quick Starts". Don't worry if you don't understand it completely at first attempt. Read it again, do experiments, and gradually your understanding will be better and better. It took me almost one week to understand the complete philosophy of Prism. so have patience! :-)

Also, you can see this tutorial if you want to:

[Getting started with Prism](http://www.codeproject.com/articles/35804/Getting-started-with-Prism-2-formerly-known-as-the-Composite-Application-Library.aspx)

.

Comment: Thanks, that's the sort of advice I'm looking for.